# View Array of objects play framework

Tags: html, sql, playframework

How do i diplay a list of arrays of objects?

i have

```
List<Objects[]> listObj
```

in the view?????
    #{list listObj as:'list'}

```
#{/list }
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [documentation for the list tag](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1/tags#list).

```
<ul>
#{list items:products, as:'product'}
    <li>${product}</li>
#{/list}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

as far as I remember it would be

```
<ul>
   #{listObj, as:'item'}
      <li> ${item} </li>
   #{/list}
</ul>
```

Comment: no it doesn't work
have already try like this
<ul>    #{listObj, as:'item'}       <ul>    #{item, as:'item2'}       <li> ${item2} </li>    #{/list} </ul>  </li>    #{/list} </ul>